# AngularJS Callbacks on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have noticed that AngularJS requires the results in javascript from the back-end server.

The current server in the example returns `angular.callbacks._0({"key": "value"});` with javascript headers. How to make the returns in the same format on Rails? Thanks!

AngularJS generates `http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value?callback=angular.callbacks._0` link from that request by default

Here is my working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Simple">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">    
    {{some_item.key}}
</div>
<script>
angular.module('Simple', ['ngResource']);
function SimpleController($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.simple = $resource('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value',
        {callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP'}}
    );
    $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
    console.log($scope.some_item.key);
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a RESTful controller responding to JSON it will work fine.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    articles = Article.all
    respond_with articles
  end

  def get
    article = Article.find(params[:id])
    respond_with article
  end

  # etc.
end
```

You can limit the attributes returned using `respond_with article, include: {:id, :title, :description}`

Comment: but JSONP requires a callback as Javascript function?

Comment: You don't need to use JSONP, Angular $resource expects plain JSON. As long as your controller responds to index, show, create, destroy, and update (or the subset you need), you can use $resource as in your example. Have a look at Angular documentation for [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource), especially the examples. In general, if you create a scaffold in rails, it should work out of the box with Angular. Also, in your example, I would have expected `$scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();` to take an argument (it will be routed to show in your controller).